# Build and run ruby without installing it to system directories

Tags: ruby, debian

I've cloned the ruby 1.8.7 source tree.  I can build ruby.  But I can't figure out how to run it without installing it in system directories.  How can I do it?

Background: I want to use "git bisect" to figure out which build of Ruby introduced a new behavior in my code.  I need to build and run ruby against a test program, multiple times, but I don't want to clobber the ruby that the Debian package installed.

Here's what I get if I try to run the ruby I built from source:

```
$ ./ruby -e 'puts RUBY_VERSION'
ÀÇ      ÀÇ      : ÀÇ    ÀÇ      : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - ÀÇ        ÀÇ       (LoadError)
```

I've also tried installing it, but not to the system directories, and got a stack trace:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/wayne/tmp/ruby/installed --exec-prefix=/home/wayne/tmp/ruby/installed
$ make
$ make install
$ /home/wayne/tmp/ruby/installed/bin/ruby -e 'puts RUBY_VERSION'
/home/wayne/tmp/ruby/installed/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl/ssl.rb:26: uninitialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER (NameError)
        from /home/wayne/tmp/ruby/installed/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/wayne/tmp/ruby/installed/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl.rb:23
```

I've got the feeling that I'm close, but a miss is as good as a mile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rvm is a great tool. and should be able to take care of the heavy lifting for switching between different ruby version (or even sets of gems).

Installation is [very easy](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/):

```
$ gem install rvm && rvm-install 
$ echo "if [[ ! -z $HOME/.rvm ]] ; then source $HOME/.rvm ; fi" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then to [install](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/patchlevels/) a specific version & patch level:

```
rvm  install ruby-1.8.7-p160
```

Then to switch between versions:

```
$ rvm 1.8.7-p160 
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 160) [i686-darwin10.0.0]
$ rvm 1.8.7-p174 
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.0.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

When I need to do something like that, I use the [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) command.  Create a temporary directory, install ruby into a `sbin` subdirectory, and `chroot` into the temp folder.  Depending on what you are testing, you may also have to copy some system libraries into the temporary directory tree (before you `chroot` in).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to use [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to test your app against different rubies.